# How to pass an Api Key in a http request with java?

Tags: java, api, curl, http-headers, httprequest

i been trying to access an api with the request header example below using java

```
curl -X GET -k --header "x-apikey: accesskey=4def6bc216f14c1ab86dfba8738ff4a5; secretkey=a47d1d3a071443449a75821129526b96" https://Tenable.sc/rest/currentUser***`***
```

like so

```
URL urlcon= new URL("https://Tenable.sc/rest/currentUser");
HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) urlcon.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

String apiKey = "accesskey:4def6bc216f14c1ab86dfba8738ff4a5; secretkey:a47d1d3a071443449a75821129526b96;";

connection.setRequestProperty("x-apikey", apiKey);

System.out.println(connection.getResponseCode());
```

May i know how to convert the curl request example above into a header for a http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have looks good.  To simulate the `-k` flag, which turns off hostname verification, you'll need to make another call:

```
connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
        return true;
    }
});
```

Without that, you'll might see certificate errors.

Comment: hmmm i keep receiving the response code of 403 (forbidden), i am pretty sure my api key is valid.  Could it be that i am not creating the http request correctly?

Comment: nvm, it is working. My code was right all along. Thanks schtever